# How can I load WASM modules in webview with Rust?

Tags: reactjs, webview, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I'm trying to host a React app in [webview](https://github.com/Boscop/web-view) which uses a compiled Rust -> WebAssembly module.

I get this error:

```
Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: URL is not valid or contains user credentials.
```

The WASM module gets called in one of the components:

```js
const { mymod } = require("../../wasm/mymod");
```

Then I use webpack to bundle it all.

```js
const webpackConfig = {
  entry: "./frontend/bootstrap.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./frontend/index.html"
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
  ]
};
```

Then I load it in webview:

```rust
fn main() {
    let html = format!(r#"...");

    web_view::builder()
        .title("my app")
        .content(Content::Html(html))
        .size(320, 480)
        .resizable(true)
        .debug(true)
        .user_data(())
        .invoke_handler(|_webview, _arg| Ok(()))
        .run()
        .unwrap();
}
```

The error in the JavaScript debugger leads to this line of code:

```js
var req = fetch(__webpack_require__.p + "" + {"./frontend/wasm/mymod_bg.wasm":"31335016d485c8fcb290"}[wasmModuleId] + ".module.wasm")
```